# custom filter in kendo grid datasource

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my kendo grid I am loading data

```
.Grid<Portals.Areas.Reports.Models.TransactionReportItem>()
```

like this. But again I provided in DataSource

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                          .Ajax()
                          .PageSize(100)
                          .Read(read =>                                    
                           read.Action("GetTransactions","Transactions")))
```

My problem is when I provided some external filter, because  of `datasource` it is displaying all data instead of filter data. 
My question is how we can apply external filter  condition in data source or is it possible to stop calling `datasource`? I am using server  side  `grid control`.

Answer (score 0):

On the `Read` action add this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetTransactions","Transactions").Data(getDataFilters))
```

`.Data()` will call the function you give it every time the `Read` action occurs.

```
<scrip>
    function getDataFilters() {
        // Add the values from you filters into variables.
        var filterField1 = $('#filterField1').val();
        var filterField2 = $('#filterField2').val();

        // Set the values of your model
        return {
            ModelFieldName1: filterField1,
            ModelFieldName2: filterField2
        }
    }
</script>
```

Make sure you have a parameter set in `GetTransactions` action that will hold this data. I don't know how your controller is set up, but you can see which fields have a filter on them, then set up a `Where` clause when you grab your data.